# Exception PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Caution my english is horrible.

No one answers in the spanish forum.

doubts :

1. ¿How can I control the exception of a empty entry? (Explanation following)
2. ¿What value is saved in the variable if there's an empty entry?

I created this variable:

```
DECLARE

v_input NUMBER(8) := &entry;
```

I don't give a value, I mean in the pop up I accept directly without writing anything.

### [POPUP IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxGVA.png)

when I read the error code ( that I will leave at the end), I came across this line.

**PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ' ; ' when expecting one of the following :**

So I guess the variable default value if you do a empty entry is -> **;**

then I thought of controling the exception creating a IF, this if compares my variable (with empty entry/value) to ' ; ' you can see below.

```
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_codigo);

    IF(v_codigo = ';')THEN

          RAISE v_excepcion;

    END IF;

EXCEPTION

    when v_excepcion then 

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('No has insertado un valor válido');
END;
```

**ERROR CODE**

```
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 2, columna 32:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo ";" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an al
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

sorry for my grammar mistakes, If it does not clear I will follow the post for give you more information.
thx

Comment: You can't control it because it is a compile-time error and not a run-time error. Maybe you should consider [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception handlers are for exceptions (errors) encountered during execution of your function or procedure or anonymous block. They don't handle syntax errors - where the function or procedure won't even compile.

You are using a **substitution** variable - one that is "substituted" (replaced) by your editor BEFORE the code is ever presented to the PL/SQL parser. THAT kind of error can't be anticipated and handled in the code - if you return nothing (an empty string) when prompted, the code itself will receive "nothing" in that place, and the syntax of your function or procedure will be incorrect, so you will get the syntax error you received. Your code looks exactly like this *after the substitution*:

```
v_input NUMBER(8) := ;
```

resulting exactly in the syntax error you have seen.

The correct way to pass in a value at run time is to use parameters (for functions or procedures), or **bind variables** in an anonymous block. The variable must be declared and initialized before executing the block (in a command line environment like SQL*Plus); or, in a GUI like Toad or SQL Developer, you will be prompted for a value for the bind variable. If you press Enter without giving a value, that is interpreted as `NULL`, which is perfectly valid. (Whether it is what you want or not, that's a different question.)

The code would have to look something like this:

```
declare
  v_input number(8) := :entry;     --  notice the leading colon  :
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_input);
end;
/
```

If you want to *handle* the case of `NULL` input, you would do it in code:

```
declare
  v_input number(8) := :entry;
begin
  if v_input is null then
     --  handle it here
  else
     dbms_output.put_line(v_input);   -- or whatever else you need to do
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Your explanation has been incredible, I understood everything, 
the last thing  ¿which is the difference between use &entry and :entry?

How can I search more information about this new input mode?

Comment: @TekeCode - that question: "substitution variable vs bind variable" - is much more important than anything else you asked in this thread. Google is your friend - do a search for "Oracle substitution variable vs bind variable" and read as much as you can about this topic. You will see that bind variables must be used in almost all cases, for many reasons: performance, security, take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *exception* to handle that; you could `dbms_output.put_line` (note that you used `putline`, which is wrong) within `IF`, or even `raise_application_error` if you want to stop execution. For example (valid value first):

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_codigo varchar2(20) := '&entry';
  3  begin
  4    if v_codigo = ';' or v_codigo is null then
  5       raise_application_Error(-20000, 'Invalid value');
  6    else
  7       dbms_output.put_line('You entered ' || v_codigo);
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /
Enter value for entry: Littlefoot
You entered Littlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Invalid values: empty string and `;`;

```
SQL> /
Enter value for entry:
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Invalid value
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL> /
Enter value for entry: ;
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Invalid value
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

---

Or, to reuse your own code: declare the exception first (line #3), then use it:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_codigo varchar2(20) := '&entry';
  3    v_excepcion exception;
  4  BEGIN
  5      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_codigo);
  6      IF(v_codigo = ';' or v_codigo is null) THEN
  7            RAISE v_excepcion;
  8      END IF;
  9
 10  EXCEPTION
 11      when v_excepcion then
 12           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No has insertado un valor válido');
 13  END;
 14  /
Enter value for entry: Littlefoot
Littlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for entry:
No has insertado un valor válido

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for entry: ;
;
No has insertado un valor válido

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand but I have a new question.

¿If I want control a empty entry of user? 

the output is :

You entered 

I tried if v_codigo = '' ;
and  if v_codigo = ' ';

Comment: The whole answer is polluted by accepting the OP's incorrect assumption... when nothing is provided as input for a **substitution** variable, an empty string is substituted, not a semicolon.

Comment: If you enter an empty string, handle it with a little addition to that code: `or v_codigo is null`. I modified code I previously posted; have a look.

Comment: The more important thing you showed the OP (which I missed in the first reading) was adding the single-quotes around the bind variable. The OP didn't have them; with them, he would not have received the error he reported. His code, as you can see, doesn't have them.